# Java enum pass as an constructor

Tags: java, lambda, enums

I am trying to pass a reference of an enum type from a constructor to test some lambdas, method reference, and `Stream`s. When I try to instantiate the class I am getting a error on the enum.

```
public class Book {

    private String title;
    private List<String> authors; 
    private int pageCount[];
    private Year year; 
    private double height;
    private Topic topic;

    public Book (String title, ArrayList<String> author, int pageCount [], Year year, double height, Topic topic  )
    {
        this.title = title;
        this.authors = author;
        this.pageCount = pageCount; 
        this.topic = topic;
        this.year = year;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public enum Topic
    {
        MEDICINE, COMPUTING, FICTION, HISTORY

    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public List<String> getAhuthors(){
        return authors;
    }

    public int [] getPageCounts(){
        return pageCount;

    }

    public Topic getTopic()
    {
        return topic;
    }



    public Year getPubDate(){
        return year;
    }

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public static void main(String args [] )
    {


        Book nails = new Book("Fundamentals of Chinese Fingernail image", Arrays.asList("Li", "Fun", "Li"), 
                 new int [] {256}, Year.of(2014), 25.2, COMPUTING);

        Topic test = Topic.COMPUTING;

        System.out.println(test);
    }
}
```

this is what I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
     COMPUTING cannot be resolved to a variable at Book.main(Book.java:70)
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: this is what I am getting :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 COMPUTING cannot be resolved to a variable

 at Book.main(Book.java:70)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Book nails = new Book("Fundamentals of Chinese Fingernail image", Arrays.asList("Li", "Fun", "Li"), 
             new int [] {256}, Year.of(2014), 25.2, COMPUTING);
```

by

```
Book nails = new Book("Fundamentals of Chinese Fingernail image", Arrays.asList("Li", "Fun", "Li"), 
             new int [] {256}, Year.of(2014), 25.2, Topic.COMPUTING);
```

EDIT:

Like @Voltboyy pointed out, you must change qhat i pointed out before and replace the `ArrayList<String>` in the constructor to `List<String>` like this:

```
public Book(String title, List<String> list, int pageCount[], Year year, double height, Topic topic) {
    this.title = title;
    this.authors = list;
    this.pageCount = pageCount;
    this.topic = topic;
    this.year = year;
    this.height = height;
}
```

and you program will work.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried doing that before Asking here.  I just retried it to make sure, and it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

As said by @djointster, `COMPUTING` should be `Topic.COMPUTING`.

But your code will still not work afterwards as `private List<String> authors` differs from `ArrayList<String> author` in your constructor.

So you should change this:

```
ArrayList<String> authors;
//to
List<String> authors;
```

in the constructor.